# <abbr />-Element: aria-label or title attribute

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

While it is recommended to use the `title` attribute on the `<abbr />` element, this has no effect on screen readers (at least not on chromevox).

`<abbr title="as soon as possible">ASAP</abbr>`

The thing that works is of course `aria-label` e.g:

`<abbr aria-label="as soon as possible">ASAP</abbr>`

So in order to be both semantically corrent and screen reader compatible I need to mark both:

`<abbr aria-label="as soon as possible" title="as soon as possible">ASAP</abbr>`

which seems a bit of a hack. why doesn't chromevox just read the title attribute instead?

Comment: That sounds like a bug in chromevox, to be honest.

Comment: what do other screen readers do?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**In short : Despite one of the WCAG recommendations, `abbr` is not a perfect solution to explain the signification of an abbreviation to everyone, `aria-label` should be used when you want to announce the pronunciation of the abbreviation.**

Screen readers are not supposed to read the `title` attribute as it is not intended to replace the `aria-label`. See also W3 warning:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html/dom.html#attr-title

> Relying on the title attribute is currently discouraged as many user agents do not expose the attribute in an accessible manner as required by this specification (e.g. requiring a pointing device such as a mouse to cause a tooltip to appear, which excludes keyboard-only users and touch-only users, such as anyone with a modern phone or tablet).

I never encourage the use of the `abbr` tag for two reasons:

- **it's not a focusable element** so you can't navigate through it using the keyboard to see the meaning of the abbreviation. If you intend to provide a pronounceable alternative then `aria-label` is definitely what you need.

For instance, when abbreviation is part of the language, you do need to explain it, but you can give a speech alternative :

> `Director: <span aria-label="Mister">Mr</span> Smith`

- **Blind people do understand abbreviations** just like most of us do,

For instance, the following sentence is something blind people can understand perfectly:

> John Smith of the NATO was arrested by the FBI.

And the following one is far less understandable

> John Smith of the North Atlantic Treaty Organization was arrested by the Federal Bureau of Investigation.

*As `abbr` is used for acronyms and abbreviations you should use the CSS property `speak:spell-out` to announce that an element must be spelled-out. You can use `abbr` tag to semantically indicate that it's an abbreviation or an acronym, but it won't have any effect on the global accessibility.*

---

If you do consider that the abbreviation needs an explanation (intended for everyone and not only for blind people) then you should give this explanation in full words without requiring the user to mouseover the abbreviation to see a small tooltip.

Bad example, when abbreviation doesn't help the readability:

> `<abbr title="Doctor">Dr.</abbr> Smith is located on Lincoln <abbr title="Drive">Dr.</abbr>`

Good example (simple is better):

> Doctor Smith is located on Lincoln Drive

WCAG promote many other methods than using `abbr` tag:

- [Providing the expansion or explanation of an abbreviation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/G102.html)
- [Providing the first use of an abbreviation immediately before or after the expanded form](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/G97)
- [Linking to definitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/2015/NOTE-WCAG20-TECHS-20150226/G55)

Comment: The issue with chromevox not announcing the ttitle attribute content may be due to an incorrect role being exposed for the abbr element in chrome: bug filed https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=538537 Otherwise agree with you assessment, my general discussion about the title attribute may be of interest https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2013/01/using-the-html-title-attribute-updated/

Comment: Yes blind users understand abbreviations but screenreeders read/pronounce them wrongly. 

I assume a valid case for both title and aria-label to be present would be ``<abbr title="Structured Query Language" aria-label="sequel">SQL</abbr>``

Comment: @user3351393 I don't think that aria-label should be used to put a non-existing word as the same word might by used by a braille terminal for instance.

Comment: @SteveFaulkner Thanks for this feedback. After looking to the source code, title attribute is used as a fallback by chromevox for any element (see my other answer). It is what I understand of http://www.w3.org/TR/accname-aam-1.1/#mapping_additional_nd_te, but it is seems to be different here http://rawgit.com/w3c/aria/master/html-aam/html-aam.html#text-level-elements-not-listed-elsewhere. Any hint?

Comment: @SteveFaulkner I had the curiosity to find that the "tl;dr" in your article had a title attribute ;-) I'm sure you did it on purpose. And, it's a very good article!

Answer (score 3):

*I'm sorry to add another totally different answer but I think both answers should not be merged:*

**As ChromeVox is opensource, I have a second and now technical answer to your question.**
http://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/browser/resources/chromeos/chromevox/common/dom_util.js

For any element (and there is no exception for abbreviations) ChromeVox fallbacks to the `title` attribute if there is no text content in the node (`node.textContent.length==0`)

Here is the order of precedence defined in the code:

- Text content if it's a text node.
- aria-labelledby
- aria-label
- alt (for an image)
- title (only if there is no text content)
- label (for a control)
- placeholder (for an input element)
- recursive calls to children

Now, it's kind of a buggy situation

1. **This example, in my opinion, correctly reads "BBC":**

> `<abbr title="British Broadcasting Corporation">BBC</abbr>`

2. **This one announces "British Broadcasting Corporation":** which is a correct fallback to an invalid markup

> `<abbr title="British Broadcasting Corporation"></abbr>`

3. **But this one doesn't read anything, because the node text length is not null**

> `<abbr title="British Broadcasting Corporation">  </abbr>`

If we except the last bug, it is not a perfect but quite consistent implementation of [Text Alternative Computation](http://www.w3.org/TR/accname-aam-1.1/#mapping_additional_nd_te)

> - *[F. Otherwise, look in the subtree]*
> - G.  Otherwise, if the current node is a Text node, return its textual contents.
> - H. Otherwise, if the current node has a tooltip attribute, return its value.

Note that according to the document referenced in one comment above, the title attribute, if present, should now be used by accessibility api instead of the text content: (http://rawgit.com/w3c/aria/master/html-aam/html-aam.html#text-level-elements-not-listed-elsewhere). I'm not sure it's a good thing as the `title` attribute was previously and is still [defined as the following](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#attr-title) by the W3.

> The title attribute represents advisory information for the element, such as would be appropriate for a tooltip